# Missing weights in custom layer created by subclassing

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I wanted to create a custom Layer in Tensorflow/Keras. I have created an Attention Layer which is called by the following Deepset Layer.

Attention Layer:

```
class Attention(tf.keras.Model):
def __init__(self, input_shape):
    super(Attention, self).__init__()
    in_features=input_shape
    small_in_features = max(math.floor(in_features/10), 1)
    self.d_k = small_in_features

    query = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    query.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(in_features,use_bias=True,trainable=True))
    query.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(small_in_features,activation="tanh",trainable=True))
    self.query= query
    
    self.key = tf.keras.layers.Dense(small_in_features,use_bias=True,trainable=True)

def call(self, inp):
    # inp.shape should be (B,N,C)
    q = self.query(inp)  # (B,N,C/10)
    k = self.key(inp)     # B,N,C/10
    k = tf.transpose(k,perm=[0,2,1])
    x = tf.linalg.matmul(q, k) / math.sqrt(self.d_k)  # B,N,N
    x = tf.nn.softmax(x)  # over rows
    x = tf.transpose(x)
    x = tf.linalg.matmul(x, inp)  # (B, N, C)
    
    return x
```

Deepset Layer:

```
class DeepSetLayer(tf.keras.Model):
def __init__(self, input_shape, out_features, attention, normalization, second_bias):
    """
    DeepSets single layer
    :param in_features: input's number of features
    :param out_features: output's number of features
    :param attention: Whether to use attention
    :param normalization: normalization method - 'fro' or 'batchnorm'
    :param second_bias: use a bias in second conv1d layer
    """
    super(DeepSetLayer, self).__init__()
    in_features=input_shape[-1]
    self.attention = None
    if attention:
        self.Attention = Attention(in_features)
    self.layer1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(in_features, out_features, 1,trainable=True)
    self.layer2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(in_features, out_features, 1, use_bias=second_bias,trainable=True)

    self.normalization = normalization
    if normalization == 'batchnorm':
        self.bn = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(out_features,trainable=True)

def call(self, x):
    #tf.shape(x) = (B,C,N)
    # attention
    if self.attention:
        x_T = tf.transpose(x,perm=[0,2,1])  # B,C,N -> B,N,C
        x = self.layer1(x) + self.layer2(tf.transpose(self.Attention(x_T),perm=[0,1,2]))
        print(x)
    else:
        x = self.layer1(x) + self.layer2(x - tf.math.reduce_mean(x,axis=2,keepdims=True))

    # normalization
    if self.normalization == 'batchnorm':
        x = self.bn(x)
    else:
        x=tf.transpose(x,perm=[0,2,1])
        print(tf.norm(x,axis=1, keepdims=True,))
        print(x)
        x = x / tf.norm(x, axis=1, keepdims=True)  # BxCxN / Bx1xN

    return x
```

Now I will build a model with those custom layers:

```
phi=tf.keras.models.Sequential()
phi.add(tf.keras.layers.Input((256,10)))
phi.add(DeepSetLayer((256,10),25,True,True,True))
```

But when I call the Layer structure by using `phi.summary()` I get following error that I cannot interpret:

```
ValueError: Weights for model sequential_84 have not yet been created. Weights are created when the Model is first called on inputs or `build()` is called with an `input_shape`.
```

I am not sure what I did wrong there, but it seems like I have not constructed my Layers correctly.

**How can I fix this?**

Also is the Inputshape=(None,256,10) but my Deepset Layers turns it into (None,232,10) which is not what I intended to get. I dont understand where/why a dimension gets reduced.

**Where does this happen?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1.

Try passing any dummy data before calling summary(). The error message means it does not know some part of the model yet, or some weights will be created when you actually 'use' the model with actual data.

Q2.

Conv1D layer's first argument is the number of filters (Which will be the Channel number of the output) and the second argument is the size of each filter.

Without padding (in keras, padding='valid'), if the input's shape is (B,N,C), the output shape will be

```
(B, (N-kernel_size+1)//(stride) , filters)
```

Therefore, in your case, (256 - 25 + 1) // 1 = 232

and your argument for filters was input_shape[-1], which is C (in this case 10)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add an Input layer to the query model that you use in the Attention layer.

See
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/174OKxsBr8-G-G7ogXjw-fLsl1Ak4tPcO?usp=sharing